# RDP with Ngrok not working (Pay-as-you-go plan)

Tags: tcp, rdp, ngrok

Ngrok forced me to switch to a pay-as-you-go plan as they're applying bandwith limit now.
In any case, when I was using a free plan, I used to enter the command 'tcp 3389' and it would grant me an IP to which I would RDP.
Now, with the new pay-as-you-go plan, I am trying the same command except that I am getting this error message:

ERROR:  failed to start tunnel: Your account is on the 'Pay-as-you-go' plan, which requires you to register a Domain through the ngrok Dashboard before starting an Endpoint. Visit https://dashboard.ngrok.com/cloud-edge/domains to register a domain and then use the `--domain` flag when starting your Agent.
ERROR:
ERROR:  ERR_NGROK_15002
ERROR:

I've registerd a domain as they're asking but then what?

tcp 3389

an IP to which I can RDP

Comment: Found a solution by going to Ngrok's dashboard and creating a new TCP address then pressing on "start a tunnel" and the command looks like this: 
ngrok tcp --region=eu --remote-addr=8.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:20535 22

So I changed "22" to "3389" and voila... it worked

But this method is a bit lacking since I need to go to the dashboard first, is there a way to make it assign me a random TCP address as it used to do with command "tcp 3389"?

Comment: PM from ngrok here. Sorry you hit this issue but I'm glad you have a solution. We've since updated the error message here to indicate you need to get a TCP address instead of a domain.

You can also use the ngrok cli to interact with the API and reserve TCP addresses without visiting the dashboard. You will need to grab an [API key from the ngrok dashboard](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/api) and add it to your ngrok agent config file (via `ngrok config add-api-key YOUR_KEY`) and then you can run `ngrok api reserved-addrs create` to create a new TCP address.